# Graph and Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let `G (V, E)` be a directed graph with n vertices. A path from `vi` to `vj` in `G` is sequence of vertices `(vi, vi+1, ……., vj)` such that `(vk, vk+1) ∈ E` for all `k` in `i` through `j – 1`.

A simple path is a path in which no vertex appears more than once.

Let `A` be an `n x n` array initialized as follow

[image]

Consider the following algorithm.

```
for i = 1 to n
   for j = 1 to n
      for k = 1 to n
         A [j , k] = max(A[j, k] , A[j, i] + A [i, k]);
```

I am not able to begin how to solve this.Please kindly help.

In question it's been asked that which one is the correct option -

> (A) A[j, k] ≤ n
>
> (B) If A[j, k] ≥ n – 1, then G has a Hamiltonian cycle.
>
> (C) If there exists a path from j to k, A[j, k] contains the longest
>   path lens from j to k.
>
> (D) If there exists a path from j to k, every simple path from j to k
>   contain most A[j, k] edges

I understand, folks here don't solve questions, but this question came in an entrance exam for doing Masters in CS and I'm unable to think of a way from where to begin and if someone just give me a Graph to consider and some pointers that'd be really awesome.

*

> P.S - Correct answer is option (d)

*

Comment: Sir, I've edited the question. Please read it once. Thank you!

Comment: The algorithm seems to be a modification of the [Bellman-Ford-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), adapted to look for the longest path instead of the shortest simple path.

Comment: I'm mostly confused between how can I take a sample digraph and what are the (vk, vk+1). Maybe if someone take a small graph with three or four vertices that'll be very helpful.

Comment: "(vk, vk+1) ∈ E for all k in i through j – 1" is just telling you that (vi, vi+1, ……., vj) is a path. Each adjacent pair of nodes in that sequence is an edge in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

> (A) A[j, k] ≤ n

No, look at the counter example:

```
1 1
1 1 

1,1,1:
A[1,1] = 2
1,1,2:
A[1,2] = 2
1,2,1:
A[2,1] = 3
(Rest is redundant)
```

> (B) If A[j, k] ≥ n – 1, then G has a Hamiltonian cycle.

That would suggest P=NP, since finding a hamiltonian cycle is NP Hard.

> (C) If there exists a path from j to k, A[j, k] contains the longest
>   path lens from j to k.

Again, that will suggest P=NP, because you can easily use it to find hamiltonian paths, if such exist.

> (D) If there exists a path from j to k, every simple path from j to k
>   contain most A[j, k] edges

This is true by induction, if you assume the hypothesis to be correct, and this number is never lower than the number of edges in a simple path, the max{} function guarantees that you keep the highest value, and by induction hypothesis, A[j,i], A[i,k] each is greater than the number of edges in simple paths, and thus their sum is greater than any simple path that uses the path based on them.

Comment: How you got an idea to take Graph as (1,1) = 1 (self loop), (1,2) = 1 and then (2,2) = 1 and (2,1) = 1

Comment: for option B) someone has this explanation - A[1][1]
 and A[2][2]>n−1
 and there exists no Hamiltonian cycle. Hence invalid. How does this one makes sense?

Comment: Also, they've mentioned simple path, but you've taken self loops. So, what gives that?